# How can codecommit files be uploaded to s3 automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The below code gives me only bytes which are changed but not the entire file. coming to s3 part the zip file is creating but with size as zero bytes whereas actual size will be some 70-80 bytes. I need a method where all files in repository will be pushed to s3 when a push event occurs.
at least tell me how to get all files from the repository when push even occurs.

Thanks in advance!

```
import boto3
import pathlib
import tarfile
import io
import sys
import os


codecommit = boto3.client("codecommit")

def get_differences(repository_name, branch="master"):
    response = codecommit.get_differences(
        repositoryName=repository_name,
        afterCommitSpecifier='master',
    )
    differences = []
    while "nextToken" in response:
        response = codecommit.get_differences(
            repositoryName=repository_name,
            afterCommitSpecifier='master',
            nextToken=response["nextToken"]
        )
        differences += response.get("differences", [])
    else:
        differences += response["differences"]
    return differences

def main(event,context):
    repository_name = event['Records'][0]['eventSourceARN'].split(':')[5]
    repository_path = pathlib.Path(repository_name)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    with tarfile.open(None, "w:gz", fileobj=buf) as tar:
    for difference in get_differences(repository_name):
        blobid = difference["afterBlob"]["blobId"]
        path = difference["afterBlob"]["path"]
        mode = difference["afterBlob"]["mode"] # noqa
        blob = codecommit.get_blob(
            repositoryName=repository_name, blobId=blobid)
        tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(str(repository_path / path))
        tarinfo.size = len(blob["content"])
        tar.addfile(tarinfo, io.BytesIO(blob["content"]))
        tarobject = buf.getvalue()
# save to s3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.filename = str(repository_name)
s3.bucket = 'csharp-codes-codecommit' 
response = s3.put_object(Bucket=s3.bucket,Key= '/tmp/'+str(repository_path))
```

Comment: What made you think of setting s3.filename and s3.bucket?

Comment: It was just added to check

Comment: To check what? Neither is part of the boto3 API. Guessing is not a good alternative to reading the API documentation and will result in code that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it doesn't look like your `s3.put_object()` call is attaching your tar file.

Another solution is the serverless samples for CodeCommit located [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-codecommit-examples). The [last one](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-codecommit-examples#backup-git-archive-to-amazon-s3) will create a zip archive after every push.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for boto3's S3 Client [put_object() method](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object).

You have not supplied a `Body` (so your S3 object will be created with 0 bytes) and you have incorrectly supplied a `Key` (the Key should include both path and filename, not just the path as you have written).

Comment: I need the part of getting files from codecommit as a archive. All files from codecommit repo as tar file.